# PDFTron set up, where do I have to copy the public dir

Tags: reactjs, pdftron

Trying to set up PDFtron in a React project using web pack running webpack-dev-server in dev, tried a few locations, still can't get the viewer to load, I have tried copying the public folder containing UI and core into my dist dir, still viewer does not load, also do I need a reference to the webviewer.min.js in my index.html

All the examples I have seen use react-create app, which runs the react-scripts start and assumes you have a public dir.

This is my WebViewer init code, I have copied the public dir into my dist dir

```
useEffect(() => {
    WebViewer({
        path: '/public',
        initialDoc: 'https://pdftron.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/pl/webviewer-demo.pdf'
    })
        .then(instance => {
```

Can someone point me to an example, please

Error I have seen is : Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

For react integration, you can read this guide: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/react/

Also, here is a PDFTron/webviewer-react-sample Github sample you can refer to: https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-react-sample

If you are using WebPack, check the section "WebPack" under:
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/npm/#2-copy-static-assets

Comment: Thanks, Oscar, I have seen this example and I have read the guide, the issue is I am running webpack-dev-server, I have no public dir like projects created with create-react-app, I need to know where the webviewer/public dir needs to be served from.

Comment: @LarryEdwardson, I updated my answer, see if that's helpful

Comment: Hi Oscar, thanks for pointing me to that, I have read everything in regards to webpack, I think the issue is that webpack-dev-server is not serving the files from dist or build but it is serving from the root / I have created a public folder at the root of the project and copied ui and core from webviewer public dir, still no luck, I have reached out to PDFtron tech support, hopefully they can help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by pulling the viewer outside of react-modal so the path issue was unrelated.

Still not sure why it will not render inside a modal.